# Perl Unit Test Mocking

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am attempting write a unit test in Perl by mocking. Its my first attempt at mocking.

Method is defined in MyConnect.pm

```
sub connect_attempt {
my ($a, $b, $c) = @_; 
// some calculation with $c
$status = connect( $a, $b );
return status;
}
```

connect is subroutine defined in Socket module. I need to test two scenario

1) Connection successful  - To test this I am planning to return a new mock object or string
2) Connection unsuccessful - Status will remain undefined

MyConnect.t

```
use MyConnect;
use Socket;
my $status;
my $mock = Test::MockObject->new();
my $connect_module = Test::MockModule->new('MyConnect');
$connect_module->mock( 'connect_attempt' => sub { return "true"});
my $socket_module = Test::MockModule->new('Socket');
$socket_module->mock( 'connect' => sub { return "true"});
$status = $connect_module->connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
ok(defined $status, 'Its fine');
```

I get the below error:

```
Cant locate object method "connect_attempt" via package "Test::MockModule" at t/MyConnect.t line 21.
#Looks like your test exited with 9 before it could output anything.
Dubious, test returned 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)`
Line 21 is the call `$status = connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
```

As per my understanding, I have created MockModule for my Module(MyConnect) and Socket module since I will invoking connect subroutine from it. 
I have set the response from both subroutines to be true. I should be expecting $status to true as well.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong. This is my first unit test with mocking. I may have misunderstood certain concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you're using the object oriented usage of the module, but your original module isn't OO.

Change:

```
$status = $connect_module->connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
```

...to:

```
$status = MyConnect::connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
```

...or, change your MyConnect to be OO:

```
package MyConnect;

sub new {
    return bless {}, shift;
}

sub connect_attempt {
    my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;
    $status = connect( $a, $b );
    return status;
}
1;
```

...then change this:

```
$status = $connect_module->connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
```

...to this:

```
my $mocked_myconnect = MyConnect->new;
$status = $mocked_myconnect->connect_attempt("122", "53", 0);
```

Comment: I opted for the first option you suggest. However it appears connect does not appear to return mocked value. It is actually making call to host parameter. Is the mocking of connect method correctly done?
Thanks